# Kali Linux авто сохранение файлов

Tags: linux

И так, у меня есть флешка с кали линукс. Я её запускаю, выбрав persistence, я захожу в кали линукс. Предварительно (ещё на винде) с помощью программы MiniTool Partition Wizard поделил флешку на 4Gb и 10Gb (сама флешка на 16)
В принципе меня всё устраивает, но я бы хотел, что бы у меня сохранялись файлы на линуксе. Посмотрев и перечитав пару статей у меня сложился список команд, которые я должен ввести, что бы у меня сохранялись файлы на кали. Я по очереди ввожу этот список команд:
(флешка sdb2)

1)sudo mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb

2)sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/my_usb

3)sudo nano /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf

Затем у меня открывается небольшое окошко. Туда я должен ввести команду /union
Но возникает вопрос, эта команда уже введена, и что мне нужно сделать? Я попробовал просто нажать Enter и продолжил (ctrl +x, y, Enter). Затем ввёл эту команду: sudo umount /dev/sdb2 
Как я прочитал, мне оставалось только сделать перезагрузку. Именно это я и сделал. После чего все файлы должны были сохраняться даже после перезагрузки компьютера. Однако у меня не сработало. Не могли бы вы подсказать, что именно у меня сделано не так. Если моего описания будет не достаточно - я могу попробовать сделать скрины того, как я ввожу команды в терминале. Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо!

Comment: Стоп. Ты в `nano` вводишь `/union`?

Comment: @don Rumata Да, именно так.

1)sudo fdisk -l

2)sudo mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb

3)sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/my_usb

4)sudo nano /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf

5)/union

6)sudo umount /dev/sdb2

Comment: И зачем в конфиг записывать `/union`? Какой смысл?

Comment: Ну я являюсь новичком, и пожалуй сам этого понять не могу. Я брал информацию с официальных источников. Возможно вы сможете мне подсказать, как нужно сделать иначе?

Comment: Ок, тогда если ты новичок - зачем тебе `kali`? Или ты учась в автошколе сразу планируешь на Париж-Дакар пилить?